# how to find sum of time difference using subtotaling in jasper's ireport

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, sum, ireport

I have created a report in jasper ireport which will find idletime of production machines. am getting the output for that. But facing problem when trying to find total idletime.I have used subtotaling concept where i created a variable 'total' passed the idletime expression 'TimeDiff(startTime,stopTime)' ,also created a textbox and called the variable in that. In the preview instead of sum Iam getting only last value (idletime) of the table.
 Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By default the calculation type of the variable will be set to `Nothing`. This will cause the variable to be overwritten with a new value for each record in the dataset. If this is the case, when you read the variable at the end of the report it will be equal to the last value from your set of data. This sounds like what is happening in your case.

To solve this you should set the `Calculation` property of your variable to `Sum`. This will add each new value to the existing one instead of overwriting it.